# Possible corrupted cache directory in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I'm having this issie in my WPF application where I go and try to open the MainWindow.xaml and I am getting this message box and after I hit OK Visual Studio freezes up. I have to close it from my Task Manager.

Here is the error I'm getting: could not find part of the path `C:\USERS\FooUser\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUAL STUDIO\15.0_14F5CF1E\DESIGNER\SHADOWCACHE\PS3KV2UA.FBQ\TLBZBZ3N.IXK\PLUGIN`

This is the first time I have ever seen an error like this.

I navigate to this path and it exists but there is no PLUGINS folder. I create one in this directory but.... after Visual Studio loads and I open my MainWindow.xaml I get the same error message. Only this time its pointing to a different folder. What is going on? Has anyone run into this issue before?

Many thanks ina dvance.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, but could not find a solution. So, I created a backup of 15.0_14F5CF1E folder and deleted the folder from VISUAL STUDIO directory. On restarting visual studio, it created the folder again and the issue was solved. But some of my extensions were disabled. I have to re-enable them.

Comment: @Insane thank you. I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: I use the Visual Studio 2019 16.2.3, There was no problem you described. You may can repair your Visual Studio and create a new WPF project. If this issue still exist. You can go to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) Visual Studio and report your issue.